# Does stronger reaction to vaccine (fever, days of nausea) mean that an immune system would have reacted the same to the virus?

Tags: immune-system, covid, vaccine

I have heard that the real danger of Covid-19 is the strong immune response. Is it more likely that a person's immune system would have reacted dangerously to the virus?

Comment: Please give a source for the claim rather than ‘I have heard’. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These studies suggest that young people have stronger reactions to the vaccines than older people. So your hypothesis is contradictory to the studies that we have for the moment:
[img 1](https://www.nejm.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/mms/journals/content/nejm/2020/nejm_2020.383.issue-25/nejmoa2028436/20210106/images/img_xlarge/nejmoa2028436_f1.jpeg)
[img 2](https://www.nejm.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/mms/journals/content/nejm/2020/nejm_2020.383.issue-25/nejmoa2027906/20201214/images/img_xlarge/nejmoa2027906_f3.jpeg)